# Is it more reliable to connect to both sets of DPDT relay contacts when only SPDT is needed?

Tags: relay, failure-analysis

I am adding a [socket mounted relay](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-automation-and-safety/MY2N-D2-DC12-S/Z3368-ND/369694) to a PCB and only need one set of contacts (SPDT).

Does it increase the reliability of the component to connect the both sets of contacts?
Are there any other issues this creates? Common practice or bad practice?

[image]

Note that I do not intend to exceed the rated current of a single contact.

Just thinking through the failure modes it seems that if a relay fails on or off mechanically it wouldn't make the situation any worse. And it would reduce the odds of failing electrically by 50% since one contact would be the first to make, and the same or different contact would be the last to break.

Thanks!

Comment: the answer would be dependent on the construction of the relay ... if one contact fails closed and still allows the other contact to transfer, then that would short all three pins together

Comment: @jsotola, good thought! I didn't think about that. This relay has a single lever, but not sure of its rigidity. In my application only the NC or NO contacts will be used direct to the load, but for fancier control logic it could certainly be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With either two 'NC' or two 'NO' contacts connected in series (depending on the requirement being 'NC' or 'NO'), the contact life would increase substantially on account of 'double breaking' being employed.

[image]

Comment: I like it! I think parallel would improve reliability too, but the double breaking is a better idea. And it statistically favors the off state of the relay which is a much much better idea. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the only down side is that I have to wire it for NC *OR* NO with no option to use the opposite logic in the field.

Comment: Sorry, I undid the best answer. I want to see if anyone has any input specifically on the parallel setup first. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ericnutsch, But, in either case, you would get one contact for the opposite logic. Yes, waiting for more answers and choosing the best is the right thing to do.

Comment: Good point! I didn't think about the opposite still having one available.